# Автораспределение размеров в Grid с вложенным Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-grid

Есть следующий control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ShikiDesk.Controls.MangaShortInfoControl"                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShikiDesk.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
               Source="{Binding Poster}" 
               Width="150" MaxHeight="200"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainName}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" ToolTip="{Binding MainName}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondName}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Medium" ToolTip="{Binding SecondName}" />
            <Separator />
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ShowGridLines="True"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Margin="0,5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <!-- //при добавлении 4й строки начинается магия
                <RowDefinition />
                -->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Тип:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Kind}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Тома:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TotalVolumes}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Главы:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TotalChapters}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <!-- //при добавлении 4й строки начинается магия
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Статус:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TitleStatus}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            -->
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Height="30">
            <Button Width="50" Margin="0,3" CommandParameter="{Binding TitleId}" Command="{Binding GetTitleInfo}">Инфо</Button>
            <Button Width="70" Margin="2,3" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding TitleId}" Command="{Binding AddNewTitle}"
                    Visibility="{Binding NoInList, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">Добавить</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <local:AddMangaControl Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="{Binding AddInfo.Visibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Честно, я бы предоставил укороченную версию, если бы сам понимал какая именно зараза в разметке творит эту магию, но тогда возможно и вопроса бы не было.

Магия включается во вложенном Grid, который расположен в 1й строке 1го столбца внешнего Grid (отсчёт от нуля).

Если в нём 3 строчки, то всё отлично и высота выравнивается по контенту, если же добавить 4ю, то высота почему-то больше, чем нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скринах выше, появляется пространство под изображением, хотя места навалом. Уже битый час вожусь и не могу понять в чём проблема..

Четвёртая строка во внешнем Grid - Collapsed по умолчанию и появляется/исчезает по нажатию на кнопку "Добавить"

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61533/discussion-on-question-by-mr-modest----grid--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без `MCVE` сложно сказать наверняка, но скорее всего причина в том, что вы устанавливаете `RowSpan="3"` для картинки.

Вместо того, чтобы использовать не очевидные отступы и растягивания разделите ваш основной `Grid` на два столбца - один для картинки, второй - для сетки.

На всякий случай привожу полный код

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Column="0"
           Width="150"
           Source="{Binding Poster}" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainName}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" ToolTip="{Binding MainName}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondName}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Medium" ToolTip="{Binding SecondName}" />
            <Separator />
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ShowGridLines="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Тип:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Kind}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Тома:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TotalVolumes}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Главы:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TotalChapters}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Статус:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TitleStatus}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        </Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30">
            <Button Width="50" Margin="0,3" CommandParameter="{Binding TitleId}" Command="{Binding GetTitleInfo}">Инфо</Button>
            <Button Width="70" Margin="2,3" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding TitleId}" Command="{Binding AddNewTitle}"
                Visibility="{Binding NoInList, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">Добавить</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <local:AddMangaControl Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding AddInfo.Visibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Будьте внимательны - правил разметку без возможности запустить

Comment: хм.. дейтсвительно.. такая разметка выравнивает высоту по высоте картинки)

Comment: @Mr.Modest конечно, а о проблеме с отступами в c `RowSpan` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321763/why-is-this-extra-space-appearing-in-a-grid