# MVVM WPFToolkit Chart несколько видов графиков в 1 компоненте

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, диаграммы, wpf-toolkit

вопрос в следующем: как лучше это реализовать?

есть 1 варианта:

1) берем 3 chart и ставим их в 1 месте в сетке, в зависимости от выбора пользователя отображаем нужный

2) создаем несколько Series, в зависимости от результата отображаем нужный

Только оба эти варианта мне видятся как костыли. Если это не костыли - то какой из них лучше?

Код разметки:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="ExpansesCalculation.ReportChart"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExpansesCalculation"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"  
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Графики"
    Height="600" 
    Width="800"
    MinHeight="600"
    MinWidth="800"
    Background="#FFF0EAEA" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <!--Rows and columns definition-->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Chart Types-->
    <GroupBox Header="Тип графика"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <RadioButton GroupName="gt"
                         Name="rbLinear"
                         Margin="5"
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsLinear}">Линейный
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateComboBoxCommand}" CommandParameter="MyParam"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton GroupName="gt"
                         Name="rbRound"
                         Margin="5"
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsRound, Mode=TwoWay}">Круговой
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateComboBoxCommand}" CommandParameter="MyParam"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </RadioButton>
            <ComboBox Name="cbChartTypes"
                      Margin="5"
                      Width="200"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxContent}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>

    <!--Date filter-->
    <GroupBox Header="Период"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
              Grid.Column="7"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Margin="5"
                       Text="C"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <DatePicker Margin="5"
                        Width="110"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="5"
                       Text="По"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <DatePicker Margin="5"
                        Width="110"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>

    <!--Categoryes-->
    <GroupBox Name="gbCategory"
              Header="Категории"
              Margin="5"
              Grid.Column="9"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Content="{Binding CheckBoxContent}">
    </GroupBox>

    <!--Buttons-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="9"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Name="btnApply"
                Margin="5"
                Command="{Binding ShowGraphic}">Применить</Button>
        <Button Name="btnCancel"
                Margin="5">Очистить</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--Chart-->
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="9"
                           Margin="5">
        <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"
                                      DependentValuePath="Value"
                                      IndependentValuePath="Key">
        </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>

</Grid>
```

Comment: не уверен, что понял что вы хотите получить. 3 типа (series) одновременно?

Comment: если позволите еще пару комментариев по коду - i:Interaction вам тут не нужен, ColumnSpan во многих случаях плохая идея.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, нет графики не одновременно, а один из типов(просто программа должна рисовать графики нескольких типов) 2. а почему ColumnSpan плохая идея?

Comment: иногда ведут себя не очевидно. Например из того, с чем сталкивались здесь - [Автораспределение размеров в Grid с вложенным Grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684528/Автораспределение-размеров-в-grid-с-вложенным-grid/684605)

Comment: можно привязать свойство `Visibililty` графика к соответствующему RadioButton

Comment: @FoggyFinder можно, но тут вопрос "как сделать лучше?"

Comment: не уверен, что тут можно что-то придумать лучше. Можно узнать почему вам не нравится такой способ?

Comment: @FoggyFinder чую должен быть способ проще. чисто чуйка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, поковырявшись во всем скажу следующее: проще вариант

`1) берем 3 chart и ставим их в 1 месте в сетке, в зависимости от выбора пользователя отображаем нужный`

причин несколько: проще с легендой работать, проще работать с осями.

Если у кого есть другие предложения - пишите.